# Maximal extension of domain of $\Psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\frac{\log(n)}{\log(x)}}$ using analytic continuation

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, analytic-continuation, euler-product

Given $$ \Psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(x)}}= \prod_{p~ \mathrm{prime}}\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{\ln(p)}{\ln(x)}}}$$

> What is the maximal extension of $\Psi$?

I think that there is a barrier at $\Re(x)=0$ but don't know how to show that.

Comment: The series converges exactly when $\Re \frac1{\log x} < 0$. I would guess it has a natural boundary at the edge of that region, so it cannot be extended; will add an answer if I can prove that assertion.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp any success?

Comment: Sorry; this has been a busy week and it slipped my mind. Perhaps I will get a chance to think more on the weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is simply a composition involving the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function):
$$
\Psi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1/\ln x} = \zeta\biggl( -\frac1{\ln x} \biggr).
$$
The series originally converges when $-\frac1{\ln x}>1$, that is, for $x\in(\frac1e,1)$. But $\zeta(s)$ can be analytically continued to the entire complex plane except for a pole at $s=1$. Therefore, $\Psi(x)$ can be analytically continued to the entire complex plane except for a pole at $x=\frac1e$ and a branch cut (due to the $\log x$) from the origin out to infinity.

Comment: I assume you can symmetrize this $\Psi(x)$ with a Gamma factor? I get something like $T(x)=\Psi(x)x^{-k}$ for some $k \approx 1.0823$. so that $T(x) \approx T(1/e-x)$.